# Bash substitution command return number value instead of text

Tags: linux, bash, psql

I try to process the result of the command in a loop, but the result of that command is unexpected.
Instead of a string, a numeric value is obtained.
Any ideas why it's happening?

```
$ psql -qAtX -c 'select json_agg(r) from (select client_addr as "{#ADDR}",application_name as "{#NAME}",sync_state as "{#STATE}" from pg_stat_replication where usename<>'\''backup'\'') r' > /tmp/out.txt
$ cat /tmp/out.txt
[{"{#ADDR}":"192.168.0.100","{#NAME}":"test","{#STATE}":"async"}]
$ for i in $(< /tmp/out.txt); do echo $i;done
1
```

Comment: Do you have a file named "1" in the current directory?

Comment: Since the variable `$i` is unquoted, after parameter substitutions, the value is subject to word splitting and filename expansion. Due to the square brackets, that text is equivalent to the glob pattern `["#,.012689:ADEMNRSTacensty{}]`, and can match any corresponding 1-character filenames. See [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual.

Comment: @glennjackman, deleting file with name "1" solved this problem

Comment: This is one of many reasons to double-quote your variable references. See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: The actual solution will be `echo "$i"`